# RPi Model B, Node.JS, Express, NGINX very slow response time

Tags: node.js

After some searching, I haven't been able to diagnose whether this is a typical response or not.

After a fresh install of Jessie lite, Node.JS 5.5.0 from node's latest dist for arm and express, set up nginx for serving my static content and be my proxy for nginx. Nginx currently serves the favicon, any of the smaller images (will use photo hosting site eventually for larger images), stylesheets and scripts. I have node running with express to generate html from jade and jade-bootstrap mix-ins.

Right when visiting the site locally (haven't exposed my server yet), I get a 10 second waiting period before the server responds. I've also noticed it takes a few seconds for Node to start running when I do start the server. Is there any suggestions on how to fix this, or is this to be expected with node on the RPi?

Edit:
Before I had nginx handle my static files, my response time was 25 seconds

Comment: What model of Pi are you running on?

Comment: A few seconds for node to load might be understandable (I haven't used it on the pi) but a 10s delay in responses seems ridiculous -- I doubt that is "to be expected".

Comment: It's RPi Model B. I'm not too concerned about the couple seconds to launch. Mainly just the webpage delay.

Comment: I am experiencing the very same slowness on my Model B. I am rendering the pages using jade. Been wondering if that is the cpu hog on the RPi. I have no graphics and really very little content but waiting ten seconds seems normal, but not acceptable.  

Oh!  I just read the answer. Ok then. As my pages are so simple I wonder about just using straight HTML, no rendering engine.

Anyone? Might Jade be the intermediary that is slowing things down so much?

Answer (score 1):

After much debugging, it appears it was the fact I was using jade. It proved to be very resource intensive. I have since switched to ejs and greatly improved response time.

Comment: I have not used ejs before. Is it an easy switch from Jade?

Comment: ejs has much more straight forward html, so it was essentially rewriting my code from the simpler jade form to standard html, with the appropriate ejs javascript thrown in where I intended